# How to programmatically call a method via Reflection and/or ILGenerator.Emit?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

Suppose I have code, that receives list of method calls during runtime:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var code0 = "DoThis()";
        foo.DynamicCalls(code0);
        var code1 = "DoThis(1)";
        foo.DynamicCalls(code1);
        var code2 = $"DoThat({"Hey"})";
        foo.DynamicCalls(code2);
        // and so on
    }
```

How do I programmatically invoke these method calls?

This is what I have so far and I feel like I am missing something.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Doing this {0}");
    }
    public void DoThis(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Doing this {count}");
    }

    public void DoThat(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Doing that {message}");
    }

    public void DynamicCalls(string codeToExecute)
    {

        EmitCompileAndExecute(codeToExecute); //how?

        /*
        var targetMethodName = string.Concat(codeToExecute.TakeWhile(z => z != '('));
        var stringArgs = string.Concat(codeToExecute.SkipWhile(z => z != '(')
            .Skip(1)
            .TakeWhile(z => z != ')'))?.Trim()
            .Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetRuntimeMethods()
            .SingleOrDefault(z => z.Name.Equals(targetMethodName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
             & stringArgs.Length == z.GetParameters().Length);


        // mi.Invoke(this, stringArgs); // args need to match type!


        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("foo", null, null);
        ILGenerator gen = dm.GetILGenerator();
        foreach (string arg in stringArgs)
        {

        }
        */

    }

}
```

Comment: Providing the method name AND arguments as a string heavily increases the difficulty as you now introduce another issue of parsing. You should separate both which makes it a lot easier, i.e. `public void DynamicCalls(string methodName, params object[] args) { typeof(Foo).GetMethod(methodName, args.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray()).Invoke(this, args); }`. You would call it as `foo.DynamicCalls("DoThis", 1)`. That’s it.

Comment: In the use-case I have, it is a limited support of this scheme. Method signatures on the "Foo" class must be non-ambiguous, as simple as the example. It could be done like what you outlined. I'm just wondering if ILGenereator.Emit has a more elegant way of doing it, like an "eval" in Javascipt or something like that.

Comment: It gets much more complicated using the ILGenerator because IL is as low-level as you can get and the reflection methods do already lots of legwork for you.